# Why does Intellij idea warn about nullpointer in that if condition?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Here is my code

```
if (!multipartFile.isEmpty() && multipartFile.getOriginalFilename() != null && !multipartFile.getOriginalFilename().isBlank()) {
            String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
            dishCreationDto.setImageFileName(fileName);
            dishService.saveWithFile(dishCreationDto, multipartFile);
        } else {
            dishService.save(dishCreationDto);
        }
```

Here is how I see that code
[image]
As you can see, the last part of IF condition is underlined as Idea thinks that `getOriginalFilename` can return null, but I've checked this with that line of a code
`multipartFile.getOriginalFilename() != null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Intellisense isn't always correct. But no matter what, you should try to avoid repeating many nested method calls. It makes your code harder to debug (as most debuggers work per line and can't inspect intermediate values). It's also much easier to accidentally miss checking for null somewhere in the call chain. And being pedantic, just because the method returned a non-null value doesn't mean it'll always do that in the preceding calls unless it's a pure function. So it could be null.

Comment: *Idea thinks that `getOriginalFilename` can return `null`* - because it can. *but I've checked this with that line of a code `multipartFile.getOriginalFilename() != null`* - You checked that the previous invocation did not return `null`. The next one still can. *What am I doing wrong?* - Calling a method twice in rapid succession, instead of storing its result in a variable and using that one for the check and the further processing. In fact you then call it for a 3rd time.

Comment: There's probably a method like `isNullOrBlank` in that `StringUtils` library which could save you some comparisons

Comment: You could verify first if multipartFile isn't null, then you could start verifying if the parameters you need to check aren't null/empty

Comment: Guessing by your screenshot, it's not the IDEA inspection, but the plugin SonarLint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Idea thinks that `getOriginalFilename` can return `null`
>
> Because it can.
>
> > but I've checked this with that line of a code `multipartFile.getOriginalFilename() != null`
>
> You checked that the previous invocation did not return `null`. The next one still can.
>
> > What am I doing wrong?
>
> Calling a method twice in rapid succession, instead of storing its result in a variable and using that one for the check and the further processing. In fact you then call it for a 3rd time.

(this was just a copy of my comment from above)

While there may be ways to simplify the condition as the other answer shows, as you also need the result of `getOriginalFilename()` inside the `if`, I would assume the IDE will complain about that one next, and at the end you will probably have to bite the bullet and have a variable for it:

```
String originalFilename = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
if (!multipartFile.isEmpty() && originalFilename != null && !originalFilename.isBlank()) {
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(originalFilename);
        dishCreationDto.setImageFileName(fileName);
        dishService.saveWithFile(dishCreationDto, multipartFile);
    } else {
        dishService.save(dishCreationDto);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify that expression by using the StringUtils:

```
!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename())
```

There are other functions in that utility class that might be helpful depending on what you're trying to do.

IntelliJ isn't always right but is always good to look a bit more in detail to our code to see what can be improved/simplified for better debugging/readability.